# npm install Leaflet.AnimatedMarker

Tags: npm

Я собираю проект с помощью webpack. Все зависимости (модули) валяются в папочке node_modules. Качаю их с помощью команды npm install. И мне нужен плагин

https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker

на гитхабе он есть, а в базе npm не найду (или я не могу найти или его там нет). как поступать с такими случаями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачиваешь с гитхаба, необходимую библиотеку, распаковываешь её в папку **node_modules** и где нужно подключаешь её в проект:

> node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: ну я так и сделал, просто думал есть более уразумительный способ. только я не в node_modules запихал, а прям в проект. потому что в гите эта папка помечена как "git ignore", чтобы не комитить модули, которые можно скачать через npm install

Comment: согласен, если в npm пакета нет, то устанавливать нужно раками - это не удобно. можно самому опубликовать пакет npm - под удобным вам, не занятом именем